# Upgraded by accident, what can I do?

Tags: 14.04

I recently run a `update-manager -d` and realized that I installed version 14.10 on my desktop. Now I saw that it's only the alpha version. How do I stand the time until the stable version is released? And what can I do to prevent harm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have 14.10 installed, you can't go back to 14.04 or before(at least resonably practically). So we'll have a look at your other options to increase stability and security. They are in increasing stability and decreasing ease.

1. **Use stable versions:** You should try to use the stablest versions of softwares available. This would increase stability to some extent.
2. **Use 14.04 in VM:** A better option will be to use 14.04 in Virtual Machine for most work. If VM is stable, this should do very well.
3. **Dual boot 14.04 & 14.10:** You may as well dual boot the two versions and keep newer 14.04 until 14.10 becomes stable.
4. **Clean install 14.04:** Although a nightmare, this is the best option to get your computer in pre-upgrade state.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not designed to be easily downgrade-able and 14.10 isn't stable yet.

I strongly advise you backup all your personal data, if it not backed up already and do a fresh install of 14.04 overwriting 14.10 then recover your data from the backup.

There may be other ways of downgrading but this will be the quickest and cleanest.